# How to close Preview tab with terminal / AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript, preview

Suppose my Preview app currently has 3 tabs named A B C open. Now from terminal I wish to close tab C.

A comment suggest AppleScript is able to accomplish this task, could someone provide a working example of this? Or if there's another command to do it directly through terminal that solves the problems it's also fine.

A related question, if I have 3 windows instead of tabs open in Preview, how can I close those from command line?

Comment: If you kill the Preview process, that kills the whole application. Your best bet is to use AppleScript to close a particular tab, and then execute that from the command line. Can you explain why you need to automate closing one tab?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @benwiggy I am not familiar with AppleScript, could you include an example or some documentation? I am automating this because I am using LaTeX to prepare the  PDF document and recompilation opens a new, so I want to add a line to my bash script to close the tab first

Comment: LaTeX doesn‘t automatically launch Preview, are you using a script of some kind? Also, Preview can reload a PDF if it changes on disk.

Comment: @nohillside I am using a shell script with the `open` in it. Most of the times Preview reload the PDF but I noticed sometimes it opens multiple tabs. So that's why I am looking for a way to close the old tab before I recompile the latex

Comment: What happens if you remove the open and just reload the PDF in Preview manually?

Comment: @nohillside that's a bit inconvenient I was curious if AppleScript provide some way automate it, but I barely know AppleScript

Comment: I need to check but Preview may even reload automatically if you switch to it after rerunning LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me in Terminal using the latest version of macOS Monterey.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Preview" to close window 3'
```

*It makes no difference whether the "Document C" is opened in a tab or separate window, in Preview.app, as long as it was the 3rd opened document.*